# Making Ruby Net::HTTP::Get request with cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I'd like to open my stackoverflow.com page via ruby.
And I'd like to see it as if I am authenticated.

I took `usr` cookie from Google Chrome and created the following snippet:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'cgi'

url = "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1650525/alex-smolov"
uri = URI(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, 80)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

cookie = CGI::Cookie.new("usr", "[my cookie is here]")
request['Cookie'] = cookie
r = http.request(request)
puts r.body
```

It does output a page, but I'm not authenticated there.

Is it possible to make a Net::HTTP::Get request in Ruby with cookie?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to call [`CGI::Cookie.to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI/Cookie.html#method-i-to_s) method.

```
request['Cookie'] = cookie.to_s
```

---

Try following code with / without `.to_s`.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'cgi'

uri = URI("http://httpbin.org/cookies")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, 80)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
cookie1 = CGI::Cookie.new('usr', 'blah')
request['Cookie'] = cookie1.to_s # <---
r = http.request(request)
puts r.body
```

---

**UPDATE**

As the other answer mentioned, the resulted string is for server output. You need to strip out `; path=` part.

```
CGI::Cookie.new('usr', 'value').to_s.sub(/; path=$/, '')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It still doesn't work at `stackoverflow`, but it could be that I am using the wrong cookies. I'll figure it out. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is imho incorrect. `CGI::Cookie#to_s` generates
string which should SERVER send to client, not something Net::HTTP should
use. It can be easily demonstrated:

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'cgi'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> CGI::Cookie.new('usr', 'value').to_s
=> "usr=value; path="
```

Code like this should work better.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'cgi'

uri = URI("http://httpbin.org/cookies")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
request['Cookie'] = "usr=#{CGI.encode cookie_value}"
r = http.request(request)
puts r.body
```

Or in case you have multiple cookies in a hash:

```
h = {'cookie1' => 'val1', 'cookie2' => 'val2'}
req['Cookie'] = h.map { |k,v| "#{k}=#{CGI.encode v}" } .join('; ')
```

Comment: Nice pointing it out. I missed that. I updated the answer to address the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you sticking with `CGI::Cookie` so much, I don't see any benefit when you still have to manipulte `#to_s` output afterward

Comment: It was coming from original question. My point was to use `to_s` to get the string. BTW, using `CGI::Cookie`, you don't need to call CGI.encode yourself.